# Remove nested dataframes which do not contanin a given value

Tags: r, list, extract, subset

I have a list of dataframes akin to this

```
example.ls<-list(cappa = data.frame(CarpeJugulum = c(98, 101, 120, 140), kiwi = c(0, 1, 7, 10)),
                 patroculus = data.frame(CarpeJugulum = c(100, 103, 125, 150), kiwi = c(1, 1, 7, 10)),
                 motorisator = data.frame(CarpeJugulum = c(97, 103, 115, 148), kiwi = c(0, 3, 7, 10)),
                 coppermind = data.frame(CarpeJugulum = c(98, 103, 125, 147), kiwi = c(0, 1, 5, 10)))
```

but way longer (405 dfs, more rows for each).

I need to remove all the dataframes which do not contain the 0 in their `kiwi` column. I feel that the problem could be tackled at the dataframe level and then `lapply`ed or `sapply`ed, but I can't figure how to do it with basic R (I am not a great fan of dplyr, just because I don' understand its syntax: and using a syntax which I don't underdtand but works makes me feel unease).

Has anyone some light to cast ? I'd appreciate any clue/help/suggestion!
Thanks in advance

Comment: `Filter(\(x) any(x$kiwi == 0), example.ls)`?  This removes any data frame that doesn't have a 0 in the kiwi column.

Comment: It's a function I've never seen but it works! Thanks, I'm going to study it a little so to get a better handle on it and then I'll proceed to reap out the non-0! (nice nick)